# Default behavior and custom behavior for changing the type combobox in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

In my setup tool I want a specific behavior on the Select Components wizard page. The installer contains several types, one of them is a custom. If the user selects one of the setup types, it is not possible to change the check boxes (similar to components flagged fixed). But if the user selects "custom", the checkboxes are supposed to be enabled.

Enable and disable the checkboxes can easily be done by changing the procedure `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange`. When doing so unfortunately the default behavior with selecting the components according to the setup types does not work anymore.

The question is, how can I do both on the "change" event of the type combo box?

I tried to store the default implementation into a function pointer and call this in the customized change procedure (see commented lines in the code), but did not succeed. I am getting compiler errors.

Here is my inno setup script:

```
[Setup]
AppId={{8D76F99A-82A1-4995-A470-BA9B69F83F67}
AppName=MyAppName
AppVersion=1.0.1
Uninstallable=no
DefaultDirName=C:\MyPath\Versions
SetupLogging=yes

[Types]
Name: "full";     Description: "Complete installation (Base System & optional 3rd Party SW)";
Name: "base_only"; Description: "Basic installation without optional";
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "Base"; Description: "Base with required 3rd Party SW"; Types: full base_only ; 
Name: "Base\Redist"; Description: "Redistributables"; Types: full base_only ;  
Name: "Base\NTP"; Description: "NTP"; Types: full base_only ;   
Name: "Base\WinSCP"; Description: "WinSCP"; Types: full base_only ;   
Name: "ThirdPartyOptional"; Description: "Optional 3rd Party SW"; Types: full ;  
Name: "ThirdPartyOptional\7Zip"; Description: "7Zip"; Types: full ;  
Name: "ThirdPartyOptional\WinMerge"; Description: "WinMerge"; Types: full ;  
Name: "ThirdPartyOptional\Notepad"; Description: "Notepad++"; Types: full ;  
Name: "ThirdPartyOptional\Putty"; Description: "Putty"; Types: full ;  

[Code]
type
  TMyOnChange = procedure(Sender: TObject);

procedure TypeChange (Sender: TObject);
var
  i:        Integer;

begin
  for i := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.count - 1 do 
  begin
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[i] := (WizardForm.TypesCombo.Text = 'Custom installation');
  end;
  //TMyOnChange(Sender);  // this throws an compiler error: type mismatch
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // try to get default implementation of types combo change
  //TMyOnChange := WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange; // this throws an compiler error: internal error (20)
  // add callback function for type changed
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange := @TypeChange;
  // initialize the wpSelectComponents page
  TypeChange(nil);

end;
```

Comment: You need to store the original `OnChange` event method to a `TNotifyEvent` type variable and trigger the method through that variable.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the checkboxes for non-Custom types?  As it is, if you change the checkboxes at all the Type automatically changes to Custom.  So the effect is the same, but it's easier for the user.